# How to remove "added" and "view cart" from AJAX "add to cart" buttons on WooCommerce?

Tags: html, css, woocommerce

I'm currently on WooCommerce with Bricks Builder.

I'd like to hide the appearance and transformation of my "add to cart" button, which is the div below (image attached). I'm on a separate page and it's an AJAX add-to-cart.

[image: Default item]

[image: The problem]

When I try to "**display:none**" the "**add**" and "**view cart**" buttons, my element completely disappears.

```css
.added_to_cart.wc-forward {
display:none;
}

.added{
display:none;
}
```

Does anyone have a solution for completely removing these messages from WooCommerce's AJAX buttons?

I want to keep the "div" that act like a "add to cart" button or is there a way to make my element act as an ajax add-to-cart without adding the following classes: **.ajax_add_to_cart.add_to_cart_button**

Comment: Please always add the code (here the CSS) you tried **in your question**, even if they don't work...

Comment: I added the css code

Comment: Only use `.added_to_cart.wc-forward { display:none;}` …  remove `.added{ display:none;}`… It will work.